# How to access secondary travis logs

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, cloud, travis-ci

I know the primary travis build logs are available on the web and with the `logs` command in the travis command line client, but I was wondering if there is a way to access other files generated as part of the build process, such as the file `/home/travis/.rvm/log/1391454748_rbx-2.2.4/rubygems.install.log` referenced in https://travis-ci.org/rspec/rspec-its/jobs/18148204

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files are lost once the build is finished. If you want to read them, you should add a `cat` command to print out to the log you see.

```
before_script: cat /home/travis/.rvm/log/*_rbx-2.2.4/rubygems.install.log
```

If the install command is failing, then you should override `install` to install the gem for which the installation is failing:

```
install: gem install XXX || cat /home/travis/.rvm/log/*_rbx-2.2.4/rubygems.install.log
```

Comment: Thank you for not only answering the question about the other logs, but offering a suggestion for how to deal with the specifics of the build failure!

Answer (score 1):

banzaiman's answer is good (it helped me!).  But if you use:

```
install: gem install XXX || cat /home/travis/.rvm/log/*_rbx-2.2.4/rubygems.install.log
```

then the `cat` command will likely succeed, and so the line above will count as as success, and the build will continue.  If you want the build to fail when the install fails, then you need to make sure the line has a non-zero exit status.  So do something like this:

```
install: gem install XXX || { cat /home/travis/.rvm/log/*_rbx-2.2.4/rubygems.install.log && 1; }
```

The expression in curly braces will be run only if the `gem install XXX` fails (i.e., has a non-zero exit status).  `cat` will presumably succeed, so the command after the `&&` will be run.  That `1` ensures a non-zero exit status for the whole line, causing the build to stop at that point.

Note the necessary whitespace around the curly braces.