# How to display testthat results in the travis log?

Tags: r, travis-ci, testthat

I am testing an R package called [eutradeflows](https://travis-ci.org/stix-global/eutradeflows/) on travis. The package contains test programmed with testthat and I would like to see the output of `devtools::test()` in travis.

There was a line in the main travis log saying :

```
Status: 4 NOTEs
See  ‘/home/travis/build/stix-global/eutradeflows/eutradeflows.Rcheck/00check.log’
for details
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21614096/2641825), I learned that its possible to display a file in the travis log. In .travis.yml I have asked travis to print that file after the test:

```
- cat /home/travis/build/stix-global/eutradeflows/eutradeflows.Rcheck/00check.log
```

But it doesn't contain the result of testthat tests.

How can I display the output of testthat tests in travis?

This is particularly important since I have `skip` instructions in the tests and I would like to know which tests have been skipped.

Comment: This [.travis.yml](https://github.com/cdeterman/gpuR/blob/develop/.travis.yml) might have the answer. It adds `- Rscript -e 'devtools::install();devtools::test()'` after success.

Answer (score 1):

To display the result of [testthat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/index.html) tests, 
add this to `.travis.yml`:

```
r_binary_packages:
  - devtools
  - roxygen2

after_success:
  - Rscript -e 'devtools::install();devtools::test()'
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly heavier weight fix to ensure that build and test only happened once. In the build matrix I put the following in for the script

```
   script: |
     R CMD build .
     R CMD INSTALL RMINC*.tar.gz
     R CMD check --as-cran --no-install RMINC*.tar.gz
     cat RMINC.Rcheck/00check.log         
     Rscript -e "\
     testr <- devtools::test(); \
     testr <- as.data.frame(testr); \
     if(any(testr\$error) || any(testr\$warning > 0)) \
       stop('Found failing tests') \
     "
     pass=$?
     if [[ $pass -ne 0 || $(grep -i "WARNING\|ERROR" RMINC.Rcheck/00check.log) != "" ]]; then
       (exit 1)
     else
       (exit 0)
     fi
```

This runs R CMD check and properly displays build output, failing on warnings or errors in either check or test phases.